# showing velue from php file in div in html file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

Basicly, In my html I have a form that consists of 2 selects and 2 text inputs. I would like to send values from that form into a php file called solve.php. This file will produce a variable called $cenaCelkom. I want to show the value of that variable in one of my divs.

I have to send tvalues from my form without redirecting to the solve.php. I have this for sending values to my php, but I cant find out if it works.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('form').submit( function () {
        var formdata = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "solve.php",
            data: formdata
         });
        return false;
    });
});
```

If this is ok, I would like to know how to get the value from my php after executing it. BTW: I am not an experienced js or jquery programmer, so please go easy on me :)
Thank you.

Comment: you need to define a callback function for the done status, http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ also set the type as json on the ajax request, then return a json string from php, the resulting object will be passed to the callback function as a parameter...

Comment: You are submiting the form on page load in case you don't know... Anyway add a success function inside the ajax and do console.log() on it to see what you get, if you don't know exactly. More info here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: jQuery's .laod() method does your job. just google it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="myresult"><div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready( function () {

   $('form').submit( function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formdata = $(this).serialize();
    $.post('solve.php', $(this).serialize(), function(result){
       $('#myresult').html(result);
    });

 });
});
```

Comment: Thank you this works, but what if I have multiple values in my php, and I want to put them in different divs?

Comment: If you found my answer useful, please mark it useful, and then you can create another question.

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the values of the inputs by using `$_POST['inputnamehere']`  from your solve.php page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$.load()` method in jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('form').submit( function () {
        $( "#yourDivId" ).load(
            'solve.php', 
            $('form').serialize(), 
            complete(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){
               //do whatever after ajax operation
        }))
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

On solve.php simply get the values via `$_GET` and use `print()` for output:

```
<?php
print( $_GET['val1'] + $_GET['val2']) // Show a summation of two numbers
?>
```